# java genric classes not working ? <Integer> depricated

Tags: java, generics, integer

I can't make a generic class with `Integer`. It works with `String`, but when it comes to `Integer`, it says that Java has deprecated API being overridden.
What can I do for the generic `Integer` types?

```
class Student<Type> {

    private Type t;

    public void SetData(Type t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public void GetData() {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student<String> s1 = new Student<String>();
    Student<Integer> s2 = new Student<Integer>();
    String s;

    s= "what the hell";
    s1.SetData(s);
    s1.GetData();
    s2.SetData(new Integer(5));
    s2.getdata();   
}
```

Comment: `s2.getdata();` - no such method.

Comment: Can you please print the exact error from console. Question is very unclear.

Comment: just do `s2.SetData(5);`.
it will automatically figure out the type.
or do `s2.SetData(Integer.valueof(5));`

Comment: @Sweeper you modified his original code, its not the same as his original post anymore. If you make edits please make sure the code remains  the same

Comment: @martijnp I literally just indented everything by 4 spaces, so that it is formatted as code.

Comment: @Sweeper I'm referring to the first line, according to the changes you added <Type> behind the student class definition

Comment: Before the identation `<Type>` was interpretted as an html tag and not shown. It became visible after the formatting.

Comment: @martijnp If you look at the side-by-side markdown, it shows `<Type>` was there before the edit. The problem was, since it wasn't formatted as code, it wasn't rendered (because HTML).

Answer (score 4):

This is not a problem with generics *per se*.

The deprecation warning is actually about this line:

```
    s2.SetData(new Integer(5))
```

The `Integer(int)` constructor has always been a bad idea and it has now been officially deprecated (Java 9 onwards).  The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)) says this:

> *"**Deprecated.** It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. The static factory valueOf(int) is generally a better choice, as it is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance."*

You should write the above as

```
    s2.SetData(Integer.valueOf(5))
```

or better still:

```
    s2.SetData(5)
```

and rely on auto-boxing.

The problems with `new Integer(5)` are:

- the semantics are a bit different; e.g.

  ```
    new Integer(5) != new Integer(5)
    Integer.valueOf(5) == Integer.valueOf(5)
  ```
- it *may* create `Integer` objects unnecessarily.

<sup>It is also possible that in some point in the future (when *value types* are fully implemented) the deprecated form may become down-right buggy in some use-cases.</sup>

---

For the record, this is what you get if your follow the advice in the original warning:

```
$ javac Genric.java 
Genric.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
           s2.getdata();    
             ^
  symbol:   method getdata()
  location: variable s2 of type Student<Integer>
Note: Genric.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error

$ javac -Xlint:deprecation Genric.java 
Genric.java:23: warning: [deprecation] Integer(int) in Integer has been deprecated
           s2.SetData(new Integer(5));
                      ^
Genric.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
           s2.getdata();    
             ^
  symbol:   method getdata()
  location: variable s2 of type Student<Integer>
1 error
1 warning
$
```

The "cannot find symbol" error is because you declared the method as `GetData` not `getdata`.

---

Which brings me to a final point.  Style<sup>1</sup>:

1. Method names should always start with a lowercase letter, and should be "camel case".  For example:

   ```
     getData // correct
     GetData // incorrect
     getdata // incorrect
   ```
2. Generic parameter names are conventionally a single uppercase letter;

   ```
     class Student<T>     // correct
     class Student<Type>  // incorrect
   ```
3. Besides, `Type` is a bad choice because there is an `Type` class in `java.lang`.
4. Correct spelling is important<sup>2</sup>, especially in public class and method names: `Genric` should be `Generic`.
5. Your code should be indented consistently.  Preferably by 4 spaces (not a TAB character) per level.
6. Be consistent about white space in the lines:

   ```
       s= "what the heck";
   ```

   is just ugly.  There should be a single space before and after each binary operator.

<sup>1 - I notice that someone has helpfully fixed a lot of the style errors.  I am referring to the style of the code as you originally posted it; i.e. the stuff that *you wanted us to read*.</sup>

<sup>2 - It really grates to have to write code against an API with misspelled names.  Most people will forgive you if you write "color" versus "colour", and other cases where there are alternative spellings.  But if you are not sure, check in a dictionary.</sup>